# Перезапись sys.stdout для Python в Swift

Tags: python-3.x, ios, swift, xcode

Существует проект на Swift, изначальная цель которого - создание Python-песочницы, в которой можно было бы выполнять написанный пользователем код и смотреть результат работы в консоли.

Конфигурация Python-интерпретатора выглядит так:

```swift
putenv(strdup("PYTHONOPTIMIZE=2"));
putenv(strdup("PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1"));
putenv(strdup("PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1"));
putenv(strdup("PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1)"));

let resourcePath = applicationPath + "/python-runtime"

putenv(strdup("PYTHONHOME=\(resourcePath)"))
putenv(strdup("PYTHONPATH=\(resourcePath):\(resourcePath)/lib/python2.7/:\(resourcePath)/lib/python2.7/site-packages"))
putenv(strdup("TMP=\(resourcePath)/tmp"))

PyEval_InitThreads()
Py_Initialize()
```

После этого возможно выполнять код Python, используя функцию  `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags`.

Помимо этого, приложение должно иметь возможность запуска нескольких песочниц, поэтому во время инициализации каждой конкретной песочницы, индивидуально для неё создается новый интерпретатор.

```swift
let _main = PyThreadState_Get()

self.interpreter = Py_NewInterpreter()!.pointee

PyThreadState_Swap(_main)
```

И любое выполнение Python-кода реализуется при помощи такой функции:

```swift
func pythonEval(operation: (PyThreadState) throws -> ()) rethrows
{

    var _save = PyEval_SaveThread();
    var gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    var ts = PyThreadState_New(interpreter.interp);

    PyThreadState_Swap(ts);
    do {
        defer {

            PyThreadState_Swap(_save);
            PyGILState_Release(gstate);

            PyThreadState_Clear(ts);
            PyThreadState_Delete(ts);

            PyEval_RestoreThread(_save)
        }

        try operation(ts!.pointee)

    } catch {
        throw error
    }
}
```

```swift
pythonEval {
    _ in
    // Например:

    let file = fopen(strdup(url.path), strdup("r"))

    PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags(file, strdup(url.lastPathComponent), 1, nil)
}
```

Код выше способен запускать Python-код в разных контекстах, как и полагалось.
Дальше стало ясно, что нужно ловить все сообщения, которые Python генерирует в процессе работы. Было предложено такое решение:

```swift
PyImport_AppendInittab(strdup("consolemodule"), {
    () -> UnsafeMutablePointer<PyObject>? in
    let moduleMethods = [
        PyMethodDef(ml_name: strdup("out"), ml_meth: {
            (obj: UnsafeMutablePointer<PyObject>?, args: UnsafeMutablePointer<PyObject>?) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<PyObject>? in

            print(obj, args) // Для начала так, хотя бы чтобы понять, что это работает.

            return nil
        }, ml_flags: METH_VARARGS, ml_doc: strdup("")),
        PyMethodDef(ml_name: nil, ml_meth: nil, ml_flags: 0, ml_doc: nil)
    ]

    var moduleDef = PyModuleDef(
        m_base: PyModuleDef_Base(
            ob_base: PyObject(
                ob_refcnt: 1,
                ob_type: nil
            ),
            m_init: nil,
            m_index: 0,
            m_copy: nil
        ),
        m_name: strdup("consolemodule"),
        m_doc: nil,
        m_size: -1,
        m_methods: UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: moduleMethods),
        m_slots: nil,
        m_traverse: nil,
        m_clear: nil,
        m_free: nil
    )

    let module = PyModule_Create2(&moduleDef, PYTHON_API_VERSION)

    return module
})
```

Код выше был добавлен непосредственно перед `Py_Initialize()`.
Затем в конце инициализации каждой песочницы был добавлен следующий код:

```swift
pythonEval { (_) in
    PyRun_SimpleStringFlags(strdup("""
    import consolemodule
    import sys

    class StdoutCatcher:
       def write(self, stuff):
          consolemodule.out(stuff)

    sys.stdout = StdoutCatcher()
    """), nil)
}
```

Он, в теории, должен был перезаписывать `sys.stdout` на собственный поток, вызывая метод `out` созданного выше модуля `consolemodule`, но вместо этого я получал ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: PyState_AddModule called on module with slots
```

Если я убираю импорт из скрипта, и добавляю строку `PyImport_ImportModule("consolemodule")` после `Py_Initialize()`, происходит нечто такое:

[image: Ошибка в библиотеке CPython]

В скриншот не поместился весь стек, поэтому скажу, что это происходит при вызове функции `Py_NewInterpreter()`

Если вернуть импорт модуля в скрипт, кстати, ничего не изменится.

Что я делаю не так, и правильный ли путь решения я вообще выбрал?

Заранее всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Я Python к сожалению не знаю, но exc_bad_access в XCode это скорее всего попытка обратиться к неинициализированному объекту. Попробуйте в XCode включить отлов всех исключений (Debug->Breakpoints->Create Exceptional breakpoint) и посмотреть в каком месте у вас выдает ошибку. По stacktrace сейчас сказать что-то сложно.

Comment: @Olter, ошибка происходит при вызове Py_NewInterpreter. Сказать, в каком конкретно файле библиотеки происходит ошибка, не могу. Исходники к бинарнику CPython не цепляются почему-то.